# discord.py edit_server function example

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

Earlier I tried to use the function edit_server, as listed in the discord.py docs here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ownership, and could not figure out how to use it. I would like to use it to make a command to transfer ownership to another user. my code:

```
elif message.content.startswith('!ownership):
    await client.edit_server(server='317161621233467392', owner='323512053862236161')`
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\parke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
   File ".\start_bot.py", line 33, in on_message
    await client.edit_server(server='317161621233467392', owner='323512053862236161')
   File "C:\Users\parke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2337, in edit_server
    icon = server.icon
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'icon'`
```

could someone possibly show me an example with it correct usage, thanks!

here is all of my code (minus my token): https://pastebin.com/yXPCjUbP

Comment: Python code that you posted is (1) invalid and (2) irrelevant.

Comment: @DYZ tracebacks should belong in code blocks not quotes. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/posting-a-stack-trace because of the nice mark down and it looks a lot neater. And also, the code OP posted was indeed invalid, which I agree. But it’s actually relevant, since that’s how it’s “suppose” to be done, just not complete. (I upvoted your comment only because of (1))

Comment: @abccd Okay, sorry about that, I will edit it right now.

Comment: @ParkerSTP I have rolled back your edit (to the correct formatted version), if you read the comment, I mentioned DYZ since the comment was directed to him. I said that tracebacks should be formatted as code, **not** as quotes. And that I already fixed it. Ps. The reason for why your code is invalid is you missed a single quote after !ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the doc stated, the `server` and `owner` takes an `discord.Server` and `discord.Member` object, you cannot only pass a `str` representation of its id.

> `edit_server(server, **fields)` **This function is a coroutine.**
>
> **Edits a Server.**
>
> You must have the proper permissions to edit the server.
>
> The Server object is not directly modified afterwards until the
>   corresponding WebSocket event is received.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> •   **server** (Server) – The server to edit.
>
> •   **name** (str) – The new name of the server.
>
> •   **icon** (bytes) – A bytes-like object representing the icon. See
>   edit_profile() for more details. Could be None to denote no icon.
>
> •   **splash** (bytes) – A bytes-like object representing the invite
>   splash. See `edit_profile()` for more details. Could be None to denote
>   no invite splash. Only available for partnered servers with
>   INVITE_SPLASH feature.
>
> •   **region** (ServerRegion) – The new region for the server’s voice
>   communication.
>
> •   **afk_channel** (Optional[Channel]) – The new channel that is the AFK
>   channel. Could be None for no AFK channel.
>
> •   **afk_timeout** (int) – The number of seconds until someone is moved to
>   the AFK channel.
>
> •   **owner** (Member) – The new owner of the server to transfer ownership
>   to. Note that you must be owner of the server to do this.
>
> •   **verification_level** (VerificationLevel) – The new verification level
>   for the server.
>
> **Raises**:
>
> •   **Forbidden** – You do not have permissions to edit the server.
>
> •   **NotFound** – The server you are trying to edit does not exist.
>
> •   **HTTPException** – Editing the server failed.
>
> •   **InvalidArgument** – The image format passed in to icon is invalid. It
>   must be PNG or JPG. This is also raised if you are not the owner of
>   the server and request an ownership transfer.

Edit:

You might’ve missed something, please copy **exactly** this, note there’s two get_server calls. Fill in the server_id and member_id respectively.

```
await client.edit_server(server=client.get_server("server_id"), owner=client.get_server("server_id").get_member("member_id"))
# you missed this part    =>                                          |—————————————————————-———–—-|
```

To avoid replication, you can do this:

```
server = client.get_server("server_id")
await client.edit_server(server=server, owner=server.get_member("member_id"))
```

**Reminder**:

You must keep `server=` and `owner=` part.

Comment: would this work? `client.edit_server(discord.Server(317161621233467392), discord.Member(323512053862236161))`

Comment: No, unless you tried it and figure otherwise. Is the server the server you send the message from? And the member a member from the server?

Comment: Either way, you can do this instead `client.get_server("server id")` for the server and `client.get_server("server id").get_member("member id")` for the member

Comment: okay I did this instead `await client.edit_server(client.get_server("server id"), client.get_server("server id").get_member("member id"))`

wither server id, and member id filled in respectively, and I get this error
`AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'get_member'`